# How do I resolve emulator java-related errors in NativeScript Skidekick

Tags: java, android, nativescript

I am trying to launch a virtual device emulator on NativeScript Sidekick and keep getting

```
"[19-04-16 12:57:55.059] Failed to start virtual device iPhone 6s. Errors:
"Unable to execute avdmanager, ensure JAVA_HOME is set and points to correct directory""
```

I am using MacOS. 
What else should I check and why would avdmanager be needed to run an IOS simulator?

I have verified JAVA_HOME is set.

```
uss-c02nq3veg3qp:~ jt7$ which java
/usr/bin/java
uss-c02nq3veg3qp:~ jt7$ java --version
java 11.0.2 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

I also have Android Studio and XCode installed (and xcode command line tools) and and verified my AndroidHome env variable is set.

```
uss-c02nq3veg3qp:~ jt7$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/Users/jt7/Library/Android/sdk
```

The adp command successfully runs.

Here is my .profile file

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/share/android-sdk
export JAVA_HOME
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/jt7/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH/:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

I would expect the emulator run as it does successfully from Android and XCODE (for Android and IOS, respectively).  Why wouldn't it from NativeScript Sidekick?

Comment: Can you run dir "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac.exe" /B and make sure output is javac.exe?

Comment: Ali, actually Joshua mentioned that "I am using MacOS")

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation. Running `tns doctor` helped me. Under the hood [this command](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/docs-cli/general/doctor) uses *homebrew* to reinstall almost everything on your machine (‍♂️), but at least *nativescript sidekick* starts to work and build the code on emulators locally.